# Are subqueries cached by MySQL when used in a WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, optimization

In the following query:

```
SELECT column_a, column_b FROM table_a WHERE
    column_b IN (SELECT b_id FROM table_b)
```

Is the subquery `SELECT b_id FROM table_b` cached by the SQL parser, or would it be faster to do the query beforehand, save it as a variable (in PHP, for example), and then pass those values in as a CSV string?

e.g.

```
SELECT column_a, column_b FROM table_a WHERE
    column_b IN (1,3,4,6,8,10,16,18)
```

Comment: Using `IN` with a subquery is a terrible idea. You are better off getting the results you want here with a join, since the query is essentially an equi-join. `SELECT column_a, column_b FROM table_a JOIN table_b ON column_b = b_id`

Comment: @TimSeguine: Why is it a terrible idea? If `table_b` is a N:M relation table, one will get multiple rows from `table_a` if a `JOIN` is used. This may be unwanted.

Comment: @naitsirch It is a bad idea because MySQL has bad support for dependent subqueries. If you can in any way avoid them, you probably should. A well chosen `GROUP BY` eliminates extraneous results most of the time.

Comment: We do not have a dependent (I think you meant *correlated*) subquery in the question (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) for explanation of correlated subqueries). As far as I see, this query should be as performant as a `JOIN`, because it must only be executed once.

Comment: @naitsirch you are right, it is not correlated. Still, old versions of MySQL optimized `IN` subqueries very badly sometimes (evaluating the whole subquery for every row of the external table, a in this case). And when I say old, I mean up to the 5.5. Rewriting with a `JOIN`, when possible, was usually a very good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into using `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` to fully illustrate the effects dealt on the subquery.

For instance:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT column_a, column_b FROM table_a WHERE
    column_b IN (SELECT b_id FROM table_b)
```

If they do not yield the caching results you wish, you may be interested in storing them either in memory ([memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php), [redis](http://redis.io/)), on file (using [PHP file libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)) or in a separate SQL cache itself.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ and to anyone who upvoted it, can you pls explain or provide alternative answers?